# How to know the IP address of the default domain in Firebase Hosting

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I'm currently using firebase hosting with my default domain.

Is there a way to check if the IP address associated with this domain is a static IP address?

thank you very much.

- I looked up her IP on an IP address lookup service and it pointed to the same her IP address for several days.
- I checked the firebase hosting reference, but there was no explanation about the default domain.

  ```
  * https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** [@pregum_fox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12318819/pregum-fox) (the OP) added in the [comments below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74554447/how-to-know-the-ip-address-of-the-default-domain-in-firebase-hosting/74555085?noredirect=1#comment131717802_74555085) that when they contacted Firebase Support directly, the team confirmed that all `*.web.app` and `*.firebaseapp.com` domains will resolve to the same IP address - which at the time of writing is `199.36.158.100`, a [Fastly](https://www.fastly.com) edge server. [Custom domains](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain) will use a different edge server identified in the Firebase Console.

---

*Original content:*

If it's not documented, it likely isn't - or at least, is not guaranteed to be.

The only time an IP address linked with your Firebase Hosting site should not change (without being advised), is when you've connected it to a [custom domain](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain). This is because the IP address you register as the A record for your custom domain must remain the same to work properly. If it changed often, using a custom DNS would be pointless.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  

When I contacted the official site, I was able to confirm that the IP address of the site hosted by the default Firebase Hosting is fixed to 199.36.158.100.   

Not so with custom domains.

Below is a quote from the email.

> All projects hosted using the Firebase Hosting service have the same static IP of 199.36.158.100.

I would appreciate it if you could refer to it.